# How to use "this" reference of the element calling the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, this

For example I want a function that is used by many elements to get the attributes of the calling element.

```
function example(){
    var name = //name of the calling element "$(this).attr('name')"
}
<button name="somename1" onclick="example()">Button1</button>
<button name="somename2" onclick="example()">Button2</button>
```

so if the button named 'somename1' calls the function, the variable 'name' will be assigned to 'somename1' and so if 'somename2' called it, it will be assigned to 'somename2'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use **This**:

```
function exampleFunction(exampleElement) {
    var name = exampleElement.name;
}

<button name="somename1" onclick="exampleFunction(this)">Button1</button>
<button name="somename2" onclick="exampleFunction(this)">Button2</button>
```

But if you use jquery, you could do

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

Without the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: `$(this)` is what did it for me (I was using just `this`).

Comment: How does javascript know that the current html element resides in the `element` parameter? I tried searching for `javascript element keyword` but couldn't find info on this.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka element here is just a variable, not the "element" type. The keyword to look up is "this" but it's not exactly a simple keyword in javascript.

Comment: How would I also pass an event as a parameter too?

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to use `this` to achieve this, you can just use the `target` property of the event object - this technique is also not jquery-specific, its just standard JavaScript:

```
function handleClick(evt){
    var name = evt.target.name;
}
```

Comment: You would still need to do `onclick="example(event)"`, so this seems pointless

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/oHegekO/1/edit)*

```
<button name="somename1">Button1</button>
<button name="somename2">Button2</button>
```

```
function example(){
   var myName = this.name;
   alert(myName);
}

$('button[name^=somename]').click(example);
```

---

or simply like: **[THIS](http://jsbin.com/oHegekO/2/edit)**

```
$('button[name^=somename]').click(function(){
   var myName = this.name;
   alert(myName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).attr('name')` - this will work only if you are using jquery bind/on/click etc.

You can modify your HTML like this:

```
<button name="somename1" onclick="example(this)">Button1</button>
```

and JS code:

```
function example(element){
    var name = $(element).attr('name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery to bind your event handlers then `this` will refer to the element that triggered the event. I'd add a class to all the elements you want to execute that function when clicked, like so:

```
<button name="somename1" class="example">Button1</button>
<button name="somename2" class="example">Button2</button>
```

Then use jQuery to bind the event handler to those elements:

```
$('.example').on('click', example);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery event binding.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'button', example);
});
function example(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believed some of the more common methods were still working but it seems they've been integrated without the need for a parameter name to be set.
This now throws an error on my browser

```js
function handleClick(event){
  let nameContainer = document.getElementById("nameContainer");
  nameContainer.innerHTML = event.target.name;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick()" name="special name">Show Name</button>
<div id="nameContainer">
</div>
```

But this seems to work.
So it seems you no longer need to set this parameter.
I believe this way is deprecated although i don't know the alternative at this moment

```js
function handleClick(){
  let nameContainer = document.getElementById("nameContainer");
  nameContainer.innerHTML = event.target.name;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick()" name="special name">Show Name</button>
<div id="nameContainer">
</div>
```